# Is there a language that transpiles to C, with better syntax?

Tags: c, syntax, compiler

CoffeeScript is a language that transpiles to JavaScript, with a clean syntax, inspired by Ruby. Is there a similar language that transpiles to C, allowing for more readable code without compromising on performance? If nothing like that exists, is there a good reason for not creating it?

Comment: Note, however, that "compiles to C" is *not* synonymous with "as fast as the original C programs". When something compiles to C, it'll often generate code rather (or completely) different from what any normal person would write in C. It might easily be considerably slower (or sometimes faster) than what you'd normally write by hand.

Comment: Objective C started out as a preprocessor/transcompiler from a dynamic OOP language into C plus a small runtime library.  But it seems to have turned out to be better to compile Objective C directly into machine code asm or LLVM asm for both speed and language feature support reasons.

Comment: What I don't like about any of these answers, is that they propose totally different languages, such as Vala. The thing about CoffeeScript is, that it IS Javascript, but with a different syntax.

Comment: C programs are fast not because they are written in C, but because they are, well, C-style programs. The language is very close to assembly, and has close to zero "high-level magic" - the thing responsible for readability. With C, you get close-to-assembly speed, but you also get close-to-assembly readability.

Comment: [pascal](http://schneider.ncifcrf.gov/p2c/) or [fortran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2c)?

Comment: @MichaelT: I wanted to mention Pascal but then saw your comment. Maybe one could add Ada to list.

Comment: I really wish "transcompile" (the word) would just die. It's "compile" and "compiler". You don't need a new word just because the output language isn't x86 (and if you think you do, you don't understand compilers).

Comment: [nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim_(programming_language)) does compile to C

Comment: The word *transpile* means (or has lately come to mean) to translate code to the source code of another language *with the same semantics*, typically statement for equivalent statement (allowing a source map to also be created). Nobody is claiming that transpilers do something different to compilers. Transpilers are a specific type of compiler.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

CoffeeScript compiles to JavaScript for a very simple reason, JavaScript is the de facto client side language and it would be unreasonable to expect browser vendors to natively support CoffeeScript, when all it offers is an alternative syntax.

In a very similar manner, the main point of high level language to C translators is immediate portability, as there's a C compiler for almost every platform and an abundance of C libraries. [Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala), for example, was [designed to](http://gnomejournal.org/article/80/writing-multimedia-applications-with-vala):

1. be a compiler for the [GObject](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/pr01.html),
2. build native executables (through the machine's C compiler),
3. automate reference counting, and
4. still be accessible to GNOME C programmers

GNOME is a traditionally C oriented project and GObject specifically is written in C, Vala wouldn't probably find much love amongst GNOME developers if it compiled to machine code, regardless of it's friendlier nature (and syntax). Not everyone seemed to like the syntax, to the point that another language, [Genie](http://live.gnome.org/Genie), was build to improve upon it.

For a C++ example, Facebook developed [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/), a PHP to C++ translator. They were trying to solve a very specific issue, CPU usage, without having to replace all their PHP code and re-train their engineers (or worst, replace them). This is a far more specific example, as Facebook scalability issues are, well, unique, and again having access to the intermediate C++ code can be useful, as PHP extensions are written in C and C++.

So a translator from a high level language to another is a good idea mostly when you access to the intermediate code is required. For CoffeeScript, the JavaScript code is necessary because of its wide browser adoption, and for Vala, Genie and HipHop because of the existing codebase. Obviously having access to the intermediate code means that you can further optimize it if need be.

But *generally* speaking, it wouldn't be such a good idea to build a language that translates to C, or any other language, if you didn't have any use of the resulting code. There are so many languages out there, if you can't cope with C, just pick an other. Coincidentally the first C++ compiler written by Bjarne Stroustrup, CFront, was a C with Classes to C translator, but that was mainly because as a new language, it was impossible to [bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29) C with Classes.

Comment: There's also Nim.

Comment: Swift can compile to C as well.

Comment: There's also Vlang.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to cover a few points [Yannis Rizos](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143722/is-there-a-language-that-transcompiles-to-c-with-a-better-syntax/143724#143724) didn't in his otherwise great answer.

Yes, many languages exist. C is a common target for compiler back-ends as it's incredibly portable and heavily optimized, although with LLVM there's not much point to it.

A few implementations I know that do this are:

- C++ (At least in the early days)
- GHC Haskell (Although the main code generator is C--)
- Gambit/Chicken/Bigloo Scheme
- ECL (Common Lisp)
- [Perl](http://www.xav.com/perl/lib/B/C.html)
- Vala & Genie

---

> as fast as original C programs

No, just because it uses C as an intermediate language doesn't mean you will reach its speed. The reason C is fast is because of the method of writing the code which is obviously different for other languages. It's just a portable assembly, nothing special.

Comment: C is very far away from the assembly...

Comment: Some people think of C as "high level assembler".  It's pretty close to the machine, but of course it's not a bunch of opcodes.

Answer (score 6):

[Rock](https://github.com/nddrylliog/rock) is an [ooc](http://ooc-lang.org/) compiler that generates C99 source.
The [ooc-lang](http://ooc-lang.org/) is a programming language with objects, first-class functions, and pink unicorns. The [ooc](http://ooc-lang.org/) is a dynamic-language and walks so far away.
It generates fatter and slower c codes. u need modified more to suite your requirement. But it is a good start point.

Answer (score 4):

[Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala) and [Genie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genie_%28programming_language%29) are both languages that compile into C.  [haxe](http://haxe.org/) compiles into C++, but I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: would you mind expanding a bit on what each of these resources have and why do you recommend these as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: haxe does c too using the hashlink target, but the code written is not as human written c, its basically c code manipulating a VM, so everything is on heap, fast on heavy lifting slow in loops, haxe/cpp is better but use GC and utilize the heap more than manual C would

Answer (score 4):

OCaml can compile to bytecode, to native code, can be interpreted directly, or [can compile to C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641084/112053).

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and why do you recommend it as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: I fail to see how my answer is a "link-only answer". Actually, I could remove the link and it would still be a valid answer. The question is "Is there a language that does X" and my answer is "language Y does X". This comment also applies to Bilijk's answer.

Answer (score 3):

- Bjarne Stroustrop's original C++ compiler, "cfront", compiled C++ to C, which it would then optionally run the C compiler against to produce object code.  C++ is about as "non-theoretical" as you can get :-)
- The Unix "yacc" and GNU "Bison" compiler-compilers translate their input languages to C.  Many, many sophisticated systems have been written with them.